# Php, how to "safe" JSON encode an array?

Tags: php, json, utf-8

I used to think this is 100%:

```
file_put_contents ('cacheHere', json_encode($array));
```

but that's only 99%. It can only encode utf8 encoded datas, so:

```
file_put_contents ('cacheHere', json_encode(utf8_encode($array)));
```

it's still not OK since $array is array, not string. I know I could utf8 encode one field by one, but I need a general solution.

Comment: Are you sure you need `json_encode()` in the first place here?

Comment: What Pekka says; maybe `serialize`/`unserialize` might be an altenative here. And that deals with a good number of PHP quirks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `array_walk_recursive`, and in the callback check if the current entry is a string with `is_string`. If it is, then `utf8_encode` it, otherwise leave as is.

```
json_encode (array_walk_recursive ($array, function (&$a) {
    if (is_string ($a)) {
        $a = utf8_encode ($a);
    }
}));
```

Comment: +1 for a cool idea, but I'd be more inclined to return $a instead of doing that pass by reference stuff.

Comment: and how about the decoding? :)

Comment: @user1929946 forget about decoding and encoding and see my answer

Answer (score 3):

The general solution is to have your data in UTF-8. If `utf8_encode` is working for you, then your data is actually encoded in ISO-8859-1.

If the data is coming from a database and you are using MySQL, you can do this to make the database results come to you in UTF-8 rather than ISO-8859-1:

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

Before making any queries.

This is just one example, it really depends on where you get the data from. See [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).